# Accessing NodeJs app running on AWS-EC2 from public network

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

Enabled `EC2` security group inbound to `all traffic`, still not able to hit NodeJs server running on `EC2` from Public WAN, but 'curl' command within EC2 works.

1. Created and logged-in to EC2 instance
2. Installed NodeJs and written simple server code y binding to below

```
    host/port #
    const ip = "localhost";
    const port = 6999;
```

3. Ran the server and curl `http://localhost:6999` is working fine
4. `EC2 security group`, inbound traffic opened to `all traffic, all port` etc
5. When tried to hit server using public `DNS URL` or `IP`, it doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which service are you using in EC2  to host your node js?

Comment: What happens if you try to curl using public IP from the host?

Comment: @JebaPrince - I'm just trying a simple node server (code snippet below). i wanted to understand the basic EC2 config (security grps etc) and Node server. just a dry run to get familier with env before i could start the project.   const http = require('http');

const ip = "localhost";
const port = 6999;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 console.log(req)
 res.statuscode = 200;
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plan');
 res.end("OK");
});

server.listen(port, ip, () => {
 console.log("server running at http://"+ip+":"+port+"/");
});

Comment: @MichałKapracki - my curl command returns "ok" message as expected.

Comment: @KalidasVelmuruganSermakasi My question was, how are you hosting your NodeJs application, are you using a Linux AMI? or other service, firewall settings vary in different cases. we won't be able to help you without this information.

Comment: @KalidasVelmuruganSermakasi is you IP address public for sure? And as Jeba Prince mentioned there may be some kind of rule that blocks inbound traffic and one that allows internal requests in. Have you checked your iptables config?

Comment: @JebaPrince - its Amazon Linux AMI and instance type is t2.micro. created new security group with inbound settings "all traffic" "all port" for testing purpose.

Comment: @MichałKapracki - Below is the iptables output [ec2-user@node]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[ec2-user@node]$ sudo iptables -S -v
-P INPUT ACCEPT -c 32 2298
-P FORWARD ACCEPT -c 0 0
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT -c 28 2350

Comment: just to try whether its  available to public WAN, i installed a httpd and started the httpd service, then added http inbound to security group. later tried accessing it from WAN browser - http://<public DNS name of EC2 instance:80/. it worked. So, not sure, if need to register my node app as service.

Comment: Nah, there's no need to do that. Ok, one more thought... how about sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 6999.

Comment: Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6999              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13121/node

Comment: at last found the issue, in the node js code, the server ip i tried with "0.0.0.0" instead of "127.0.0.1", it worked. thank you so much for guiding with possible solutions , @MichałKapracki and #jeba

Comment: I was just going to lead you that way. I'll write an answer so others can fix this. :)

Comment: @KalidasVelmuruganSermakasi glad that you found the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion in comments it turned out that you didn't listen on the right interface. So in order to make your `node` server visible to the world you need to check the following:

1. Does your security group allow input on that specific port (I don't recommend using `all traffic`) instead it's better to allow HTTP in or a port of your choice.
2. Check if a firewall is on and if so remember to open inbound ports on `INPUT` chain.
3. Make sure your application listens on an external interface. This means that instead of using `127.0.0.1` as in `.listen()` pass `"0.0.0.0"` - this will make your server available on all the interfaces on the server.

Comment: Thank you @MichalKapracki so much for the best practices recommendation. Indeed it helps!